# Making an offline basic html/jquery shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-files, shopping-cart

I could use some help on navigating this. I have gone with making a basic "add to cart" submit form button setup. I would like to be able to have a separate area on the right to 'clone' them? into that list, and calculate their price in a different currency like "P 2000" Lastly when checkout button to write whatever is in the list send it in an email.

so my html looks like this,

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Dark Magic II P2000
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_desc" value="Dark Magic II" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_price" value="2000.00" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
            </li>
            <li>Northstar P2500
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_desc" value="Northstar" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_price" value="2500.00" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

I do have jquery I just did not include it for now.

Much help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: It will not be possible to write a file using HTML or JavaScript alone. :(

Comment: Besides, it's a bad idea to write a shopping cart to a file. Just write it to a database, where it can be recovered on login.

Comment: thanks for the input to help me avoid wasting my time!, any inputs on making the shopping cart itself?

Comment: You want ideas for the server-side code or for the page itself?

Comment: just page itself like getting the list to make copies of items in another list

Comment: The best you can do is to use cookies (hard-limit of 4kb) or LocalStorage (in ie6-8, you have a similar technique, with an hard-limit or 1MB). You can try to fetch the data from the server, then the user adds an item to the card, you use JSON and add it to the storage 'engine' that you want (there are plugins and libraries for this). In case you want to use something more similar to a DB, you can use IndexedDB and (if I'm correct) WebSQL. There are libraries for that too. My preference: server-side database with registration required to recover the cart (but still session-based).